# How do you troubleshoot search tracking not working with the Google Analytics module?

Tags: 6, search, google-analytics

I have a site that uses the Google Analytics module. Analytics is working fine. However, I enabled search tracking in the module -- and updated the query string to search in GA -- but search data is not being tracked. After 72 hours I'm not seeing any search data.

I'm unsure how I can troubleshoot this. I reviewed the JS routine being output on the search page and verified the GA code is appearing, though I don't see anything specifically relating to search (not sure it would output anything different).

How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [GA debug chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) for troubleshooting this issue. It will give you better insight into what is being sent to GA from Drupal

Comment: This tool is very handy, thanks! I see it sending the tracking code, but I don't see it sending anything search specific. Still, this answers the question. Thanks!